# Iterate through list in XSLT and assign it to Java Object

Tags: xslt

I have XML file which contains a list, i want to iterate though this list in XSLT and assigned each element to Java Array/List.

My Input XML is in below format

I tried with for-each iteration but not able to assign value to Java list

```
<values>
<value>1</value>
<value>2</value>
<value>3</value>
```

Can someone help me with XSLT which will help me to form Array/List after iterating through ?

Comment: Which  XSLT processor do you use? Can you show us the exact type ( e.g. of elements nodes, of strings or of a certain number type) you want?

Comment: Interfaces between XSLT and Java depend on which XSLT processor you are using. Note that because adding something to an external list is an operation that has side-effects, and is dependent on order of execution, the results may not be 100% predictable. I wonder if you really need to do it this way: if you explain your actual problem, rather than the way you are currently tackling it, we might be able to suggest alternative approaches.

Answer (score 0):

This XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="list-to-array.xsl"?>
<data>
  <values>
    <value>1</value>
    <value>2</value>
    <value>3</value>
  </values>
</data>
```

And, this XSL

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="values">
    <xsl:text>values = [</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="value">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Will print out

```
values = [1,2,3]
```

Hopefully, this helps to get things moving.